# How to find the splitting field of f over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am stuck at this assignment. I am supposed to show that if α is a root of f then K = $\mathbb{Q}(i, α)$ and determine [K : $\mathbb{Q}]$. (Hint: Consider the polynomial g(y) := $y^2 − 4y + 1$ and use that $α^4$ is a root of g.)

f(x)=$x^8-4x^4+1$ and K be a splitting field of f over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I have until now shown that f(x) is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. I have found the roots of f to be:

$\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt{3}}$

$\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}}$

$-\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt{3}}$

$-\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}}$

$\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt{3}}i$

$\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}}i$

$-\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt{3}}i$

$-\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}}i$

I don't know how to get further so I am hoping that some of you might be able to help me.

Comment: You have the zeros, so you simply adjoin them to $\Bbb{Q}$. But, undoubtedly your teacher wants to work out things like the extension degree (of the splitting field), so you may want to minimize the number of elements you adjoin. Here's a hint: $(2+\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)=1$, so the same applies to their fourth roots.

Comment: Hi Jyrki
Thank you for your help. 
What do you mean when you say the zeros, what are the zeroes? Is it the roots? And how do I adjoin the zeros to Q?

Comment: Yeah, *zeros=roots*. Typically extension fields of $\Bbb{Q}$ are described by listing a bunch of generators. Like you get the splitting field of $x^2-2$ by adjoining the roots, $\pm\sqrt2$, and end up with the splitting field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. There is no need to adjoin $-\sqrt2$ for the field axioms force the inclusion of the negative root, so it suffices to adjoin one of the roots. But, have you reviewed the examples of splitting fields from the lecture notes /textbook? Surely this "adjoining" process is described there. Possibly in different language?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I understand it better now but I am still confused about how to adjoin the roots? I have looked in my textbook and there are several examples but I am still confused. :)

Comment: Hi again! I have now tried and I used the hint  "(2+√3)(2−√3)=1, so the same applies to their fourth roots". $\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}}\cdot\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt[4]{(2-\sqrt{3})(2+\sqrt{3})}=\sqrt[4]{1}=\pm1\in\mathbb{Q}$. So now, if we can say that the splitting field is either $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}}$, or $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Because if I say that the splitting field is  $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}})$, we have that $\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}}\cdot\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt[4]{(2-\sqrt{3})(2+\sqrt{3})}=\sqrt[4]{1}=\pm1\Rightarrow \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}}}=\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt{3}}$. Since we have that $\pm 1\in \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}})$, and $\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}}\in\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}})$, then their quotient $\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt{3}}\in\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2-\sqrt{3}})$

Comment: This is how far I have gotten but I am not sure about whether it is correct or not?